# Hive aggregate functions don't work

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, aggregate-functions, hiveql

Help please,

When i try execute HiveQL command (type of both fields INT):

```
select cited3, count(citing)
from cite2
group by cited3;
```

I get message:

> Job Submission failed with exception 'java.net.ConnectException(Call
>   From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: 
>   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused)' FAILED: Execution
>   Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

I gave permissions to all table, by command:

`bin/hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /user*`

But it doesn't help, another hive command, like (create table, select * from are working)

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Hive aggregate functions run mapreduce in backgroud, and from your error log there seems Master(Namenode) is down. But create table statement doesn't execute any mapreduce. It stores metadata in hive metastore, and that seems working.